# py2app installation error--Permission Denied

Tags: python, py2app

I am trying really REALLY hard to install py2app, but whenever I run the install command on the source code, I get half way through and then I get a permission denied error. Does anyone have an idea about how I could fix this? I do have admin rights on the machine I am using. I am using the admin's profile to do the installation...so I am really stumped. Any help would be awesome.

I am running Mac OS X 10.6.8
I am using Python 2.7 (64 bit, but running with the 32 bit preferences)
I am using wxPython (32 bit because that is all that wxPython has to offer on a Mac)

Comment: Operating system and version information would be useful. The py2app page at the python wiki suggests running the installation with sudo.

Comment: Sudo is indeed the correct answer. It took me a minute to get to it, but that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a long time. Try running it as admin.